# How to update blob field using simple hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, blob

I have `Inputstream/byte[]` of an image file, which I want to store in DB, but I already stored the entity only I want to update the blob field, I have Id of the row.
I tried following but it is not working for me:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery( "update tableName set blobFieldName=:blbContent where id=5);

query.setBinary("blbContent",myByteArray)

int val = query.executeUpdate();
```

n this val returned 1, but actually in DB there is no updation happened...I can't understand where I'm wrong.
Please help me. I need this working...

Comment: 2 things: a) you can't stream in byte data in a DML statement without encoding it b) your statement has "blobFieldName" - is that where the blob is stored?  You should be using the hibernate session to persist the object.

Comment: Many databases do not allow direct manipulation of LOB data in this manner.  That said, if your database does not it should be throwing an SQLException.  If the statement "succeeds" then I would have to think you are having a different problem.  Did you commit transaction?

Comment: yeah...I just forgot to commit the transaction..Its working now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, but I found a solution.

I'll share my code with you:

```
//this is a update method
**public boolean updateImage(Image image) { 

    Session session = template.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.saveOrUpdate(image);

    session.flush();

    transaction.commit();

    session.close();

    return true;
}**
```

the below is my `Image` class, I use the image type  is Blob

```
public class Image {


    private int id;

    private Blob image;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Blob getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Blob image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.